# Getting error npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL while running npm install

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, npm-install

While installing `npm install` am getting below error. Following are my node version.

OS : MacOS Big Sur V11.6.2

```
Macs-MacBook-Pro-3:slides mac$ node -v
v16.13.1
Macs-MacBook-Pro-3:slides mac$ npm -v
8.3.0
```

```
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "workspace:": workspace:*

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mac/.npm/_logs/2022-01-01T02_28_04_430Z-debug-0.log
```

Any help here ?

Comment: happens to me as well, this looks relevant: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5340

Comment: Do you have a `"[packageName]": "workspace:[version]"` dependency for pnpm? If so you need to use pnpm instead (https://pnpm.io/workspaces)

Answer (score 6):

You can resolve this error instead of mentioning as `workspace:*` replace it with `file:*`. It helps me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `yarn` command with `-W` flag instead of `npm` command which might be helpful.

I could resolve the same issue in this way.

Running this command will add the dependency to the workspace root rather than the workspace itself, which might not be what you want - if you really meant it, make it explicit by running this command with yarn again with the -W flag (or --ignore-workspace-root-check).
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Answer (score 1):

I got this because I accidentally tried running `npm install -D postcss` in a project being managed by pnpm. `pnpm install -D postcss` worked.

Answer (score 0):

This successfully installed gulp:

```
yarn add gulp -i
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -3):

You can write this command on your terminal/cmd:

```
sudo npm install -g npm-reinstall
```

and try `npm i {package_name}` again

```
npm i nodemon
```

for example ^

Comment: It got resolved after changes `"@slidev/cli": "workspace:*",` to `"@slidev/cli": "file:*", Thanks for answer.